# how to find the solution to such problem.

Tags: statistics

In certain city of certain country, girls are not encouraged to pursue higher education; typically 20% of candidates who appear in a centrally held exams are girls. However, girls are very hard working, and percentage of girls who pass the exam is 2.5 times the percentage of boys who pass the exam. Let the probability of boy passing the exams is 0.3. A friend tells you that his relative has recently passed the exam. What is the probability that relative is a boy?

Comment: Imagine that 100 students took the exam. How many were boys? girls? How many of the boys passed? Girls? Of those who passed, what fraction of them are boys?

Comment: Law of Total Probability to get P(Pass); Bayes' Theorem to get P(Boy|Pass).